# Cognos - How to extract query name, data item names, and expressions into a file (excel or txt)

Tags: extract, cognos

I wanted to know if there was a quick way to get all the data items from my cognos report from each query and it's expression and be able to extract it into a text or excel file. I think possibly something can be done with the XML though I'm not too familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

First copy your report specification to clipboard: 
[image: Copy Report to Clipboard]

Then open XML Editor that support XPath and issue the following expression:

```
 /report/queries/query
```

Copy the result to additional XML file and open it in Excel as XML table. 
You should get result similar to this (Excel 2010):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or just save your report as XML and open it in Excel